# Uncaught ReferenceError: AFRAME is not defined

Tags: angular, aframe

Installed the aframe-animation-component (https://www.npmjs.com/package/aframe-animation-component/v/5.1.1) in my Angular project yet I keep getting this error in my console? Any reason why?